# Calculating percentages per product using aggregate functions and group by

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table with 5 rows representing two different products. The columns include the product, sales, discount. I'm trying to calculate the percentage of sales per product that included a discount. The table looks like this:

| product | sales | discount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 0 |
| 1 | 10 | 5 |
| 2 | 20 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 | 0 |
| 2 | 20 | 10 |

My results should look like the below (which I know because I've calculated this in Excel):

| product | perc_discount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50.00 |
| 2 | 66.67 |

For each of the two products we are calculating the count of sales with discount divided by the total count of sales, so for product 1 it would be (1/2)*100 = 50.

My SQL code looks like the below:

```
SELECT
    product,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sales WHERE discount >0)/COUNT(*)*100 AS perc_discount
FROM sales
GROUP BY product
```

However, the result I'm getting is:

| product | perc_discount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 150.0 |
| 2 | 100.0 |

It seems to be calculating the total count of discounted sales in the table and diving it by the count of each product and I can't seem to figure out how to change it. Any ideas on how I can improve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation. For example:

```
select
  product,
  100.0 * count(case when discount <> 0 then 'x' end) / count(*) as perc_discount
from sales
group by product
```

Answer (score 0):

How about *conditional sum*?

```
SQL> select product,
  2         round(sum(case when discount > 0 then 1 else 0 end) / count(*) * 100, 2) perc_discount
  3  from sales
  4  group by product;

   PRODUCT PERC_DISCOUNT
---------- -------------
         1            50
         2         66,67

SQL>
```

So: add `1` for every discount row per `product`. Divide that sum with total number of rows per `product` (that's `count`). Round the result to 2 decimals (so that it looks prettier).